# I have a problem with focusing a child to affect a parent

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have this code in HTML:

```
<div class="firstname-input">
  <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" placeholder="First name">
  <button onclick="showName()"><figure></figure></button>
</div>
```

I want to add border: 2px solid #f90; to .firstname-input, at focus the input
And if I write this:

```
.firstname-input input:focus .firstname-input {
    opacity: .1;
}
```

This isn't working.

Comment: You want .firstname-input to get a border when the element #firstname is focused?

Comment: That's exactly what I mean.

Comment: While it's possible to use the `focus-within` selector in this specific case, please note that you generally can't traverse upwards to style a parent based on a child (hence the *cascading* portion of *Cascading Style Sheets*).

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
.firstname-input:focus-within {}
```

and add your chosen styles

Comment: Learn something new every day

Comment: Thank you so much! But unfortunately, it doesn't work on Internet Explorer. Don't pay attention to this browser, or is there any other way?

Comment: @hello If you need to support Internet Explorer, you'll need to go an alternative route (JavaScript). In the future, please make sure to note any browser support specifications in your question :)

Comment: Okay! Thank you! :)